# How can I extract a list out of a non-pivot matrix that looks like a pivot table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a non-pivot matrix which I want to convert into a list with the column variables represented in one column as characteristics of each row. However, there are two separate fields to examine by column and build out into separate columns.

I attempted to turn the matrix into a pivot so I could deconstruct it there, but it won't accept two different column variables.

In addition, I have tried using an index formula to pull the value in each variable's row based on which column my value is from, but it has provided #VALUE! errors.

```
|  Option 1   | A  | A  | A  | B  |  B  | B  | C  | C  | C  |    
| Option 2    | X  | Y  | Z  | X  | Y   | Z  | X  | Y  | Z  |    
| Houston     | 45 | 40 | 85 | 39 | 2   | 24 | 77 | 82 | 35 |    
| Tallahassee | 20 | 68 | 23 | 94 | 100 | 77 | 99 | 46 | 31 |    
| Albany      | 83 | 93 | 44 | 62 | 39  | 62 | 43 | 83 | 61 |
```

As you can see above - each value has a row in addition to two column variables. I want to transform it to as it is below - the city and each variable as values of a row.

```
|    City     | Option 1 | Option 2 | Value |    
| Houston     | A        | X        |    45 |    
| Houston     | A        | Y        |    40 |    
| Tallahassee | A        | X        |    20 |    
| Tallahassee | A        | Y        |    68 |    
| Albany      | C        | Y        |    83 |    
| Albany      | C        | Z        |    61 |
```

Please respond if I can clarify at all! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Power Query. First, you need a formula that combines the first two rows of data into one cell, like this one, copied to the right.

```
=D2&" - "&D3
```

Use a label like "City" for the first column. Now bring the data into Power Query with Data > From Table / Range and do **not** tick the box for "my table has headers". Excdl will then use "Column1, Column2" etc, for the column names and the formulas stay intact if you need to repeat the process with new data.

Inside the Power Query Editor, perform the following steps

- Use First Row as Headers (home ribbon)
- select the City column and use Transform ribbon > Unpivot dropdown > unpivot other columns
- In the city column use the filter to untick Option1 and Option2
- select the Attribute column and use Transform ribbon > Split column to split the column with the custom delimiter `-` (that is space dash space, i.e. the same delimiter used in the formula in the spreadsheet to combine the option rows)
- rename the columns and save the query.

The screenshot shows the source data converted to a table with the formula in row 2. The green table is the result of the Power Query and would typically be on a different sheet. You can now use new data in the same table and simply refresh the query.

Power Query is called Get & Transform in Excel 2016 and higher and can be installed as an add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **Pivot Table and PivotChart Wizard**.

Check out this article to find out how to use it in your version of Excel: [Where are Pivot Table and PivotChart Wizard in Excel 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019 and 365](https://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/where-pivot-table.html)

Follow the following steps to convert the data into the desired structure.

[image: Answer]